Get events between specific date range
I am building a module that shows the available days in the next month based on the events in the Calendar Plugin.
$criteria = Event::find();
$criteria->calendarId = $calendarId;
$criteria->orderBy('startDate ASC');
$events = $criteria->all();

How can I extend this to only return start dates between a specific date range?
It seems that $criteria->startDate, $criteria->start and $criteria-> dateRangeStart  all don't exist.
I can of course filter them afterwards but that won't be very performant.
